# how do you style in css the input file button? if you have another input also like this one it's supposed to be side by side

Tags: html, css

The input file type should be beside the 1 column like this code

```html
<input type="" placeholder="write a message">
<input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile">
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just put the class in each input and give CSS accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what specifically you want to achieve, but if you'd like to, then you could style your **input file button** like this:

```css
#myfile {
  position: relative;
  top: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: calibri;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px dashed #BBB;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #DDD;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```